# Table doesn't exists using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm definitely new in hibernate and this actually bugs me. It can find the table even though the query is correct. What could be the solution in this problem?

This is the part of my dao where the error persists--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@Override
    public void emptyCart() {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String sqlQuery = "DELETE from ShoppingCart";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);

        query.executeUpdate();

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Below is the stacktrace-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/NutsAboutCandyWebProject] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db_nutsaboutcandy.shopping_cart_shopping_cart' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2441)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:374)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1286)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
        at com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.dao.SQLShoppingCartDataAccess.emptyCart(SQLShoppingCartDataAccess.java:61)
        at com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.service.ServiceFacadeImpl.emptyCart(ServiceFacadeImpl.java:221)
        at com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.controller.OrderController.orderSuccessful(OrderController.java:209)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

ShoppingCart entity

```
package com.nutsaboutcandywebproject.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "shopping_cart", catalog = "db_nutsaboutcandy")
public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer cartId;
    private Integer userId;
    private Integer productId;
    private Integer sizeId;
    private Integer numberOfItems;


    private List<ShoppingCart> cart;

    @ElementCollection
    public List<ShoppingCart> getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(List<ShoppingCart> cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(){
        super();
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Integer cartId, Integer userId, Integer productId,
            Integer sizeId, Integer numberOfItems) {
        super();
        this.cartId = cartId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.sizeId = sizeId;
        this.numberOfItems = numberOfItems;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="cart_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getCartId() {
        return cartId;
    }

    public void setCartId(Integer cardId) {
        this.cartId = cardId;
    }

    @Column(name="user_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }



    @Column(name="product_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }


    @Column(name="size_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getSizeId() {
        return sizeId;
    }

    public void setSizeId(Integer sizeId) {
        this.sizeId = sizeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "number_of_items", nullable = false)
    public Integer getNumberOfItems() {
        return numberOfItems;
    }

    public void setNumberOfItems(Integer numberOfItems) {
        this.numberOfItems = numberOfItems;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, you really have a table named `shopping_cart_shopping_cart`in your database? Why do you call `sqlQuery`a query that is NOT a SQL query, but a HQL query?

Comment: I don't have that table. I don't know why it became like that but the table name is specified in the query itself. With regards to the variable name, because I converted my queries from sql to hql and I haven't changed their names yet.

Comment: No, the table name is not in the query. The query is a HQL query. HQL never uses table and column names. It always uses entity names and their field names. Check the `@Table` annotation of the ShoppingCart entity, and fix its name. Then read the javadoc of `createQuery()` and the reference documentation of HQL. SQL != HQL.

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad again.. I've edited the question and added the ShoppingCart entity.

Comment: Why do you have a list of shopping carts in your shopping cart? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I used that to get and set a list of all my cart. Is that the one that causes the problem ?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. What you're doing is that you're telling Hibernate that each shopping cart contains a list of shopping carts. This is not the reality. To get a list of all your shopping carts, you execute an HQL query: `select c from ShoppingCart c`, and Hibernate will query the database and return the list of shopping carts.

Comment: @JBNizet If you turn that into an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a HQL query, not a SQL query. So `ShoppingCart` is an entity name, not a table name. HQL never uses table and column names. It always uses entity names and their field names.

You're telling Hibernate that each shopping cart contains a list of shopping carts. This is not the reality.

To get a list of all your shopping carts, you execute an HQL query:

```
select c from ShoppingCart c
```

and Hibernate will query the database and return the list of shopping carts.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem.
I set the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update" in config file.

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

So the list of possible options are,

validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
update: update the schema.
create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.